# Java - logger output to Jenkins log

Tags: logging, console, output, stdout

I am fairly new to Jenkins.

I have a spring boot app and would like to log output as the code executes. I have been unable to figure out how to set up a Jenkins logger which will allow me to view the console output from my java application in the Jenkins interface.

Any details would be appreciated. I am unsure what logger to pick in Jenkins and then how to call that logger from my application.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

not so clear what jenkins has to do with springboot output...

spring boot can use logback for logging, However, if you run your application from jenkins (ie, testing maybe) then you can use 'tee' to split output also to a log to a file :

```
// example pipeline
node {
    stage "Run spring boot app"

    sh """
        # running the app and split output to a log file (also)
        java -jar {spring executable file} | tee app.log 
    """
}
```

Then you will have a log file in the job workspace